# Mapping a range of integers to a single integer

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a function which receives an integer as an input and depending on what range this input lies in, assigns to it a difficulty value. I know that this can be done using if else loops. I was wondering whether there is a more efficient/cleaner way to do it.

I tried to do something like this

```
TIME_RATING_KEY ={
    range(0,46):1,
    range(46,91):2,
    range(91,136):3,
    range(136,201):4,
    range(201,10800):5,
}
```

But found out that we can use range as a key in dict(right?). So is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably just to write a short function:

```
def convert(n, difficulties=[0, 46, 91, 136, 201]):
    if n < difficulties[0]:
        raise ValueError
    for difficulty, end in enumerate(difficulties):
        if n < end:
            return difficulty
    else:
        return len(difficulties)
```

Examples:

```
>>> convert(32)
1
>>> convert(68)
2
>>> convert(150)
4
>>> convert(250)
5
```

---

As a side note: You *can* use a `range` as a dictionary key in Python 3.x, but not directly in 2.x (because `range` returns a list). You could do:

```
TIME_RATING_KEY = {tuple(range(0, 46)): 1, ...}
```

However that won't be much help!

Answer (score 3):

You can implement an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). This kind of data structures are able to return all the intervals that intersect a given input point.
In your case intervals don't overlap, so they would always return 1 interval.

Centered interval trees run in `O(log n + m)` time, where `m` is the number of intervals returned (1 in your case). So this would reduce the complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.

The idea of these interval trees is the following:

- You consider the interval that encloses all the intervals you have
- Take the center of that interval and partition the given intervals into those that end before that point, those that contain that point and those that start after it.
- Recursively construct the same kind of tree for the intervals ending before the center and those starting after it
- Keep the intervals that contain the center point in two sorted sequences. One sorted by starting point, and the other sorted by ending point

When searching go left or right depending on the center point. When you find an overlap you use binary search on the sorted sequence you want to check (this allows for looking up not only intervals that contain a given point but intervals that intersect or contain a given interval).

It's trivial to modify the data structure to return a specific value instead of the found interval.

---

This said, from the context I don't think you actually need to reduce the efficiency of this lookup and you should probably use the simpler and more readable solution since it would be more maintainable and there are less chances to make mistakes.

However reading about the mroe efficient data structure can turn out useful in the future.